# how much probability can be between mean and median?

Tags: probability

I have a unknown probability density function f(x).  It has bounded max value. and it is only positive between $[a,b]$

Let us say mean is $\mu$ and $m$ is the median. And the mean is greater, $\mu>m$

Is there any guarantee or properties for $\int_{m}^{\mu} f(x)dx$?

Comment: It may be helpful to know that $|\mu - m|\leq \sigma$ if the distribution has finite variance.

Answer (score 3):

The most extreme difference between mean and median is when (just over) half the probability is at $a$ and (just under) half is at $b$.  The median is then $a$ and the mean is (just under) $\frac 12(a+b)$  This causes your integral to be zero.

On the other hand, you can again put (just over) half the weight at $a$, $\frac 1n$ of the weight at  $b$ and the rest uniform on $(a,a+\frac 1{n}(b-a))$.  The mean is now higher than $a+\frac 1n(b-a)$.  You can approach half the weight being between $m$ and $\mu$ with this.